Get context from previous airflow task
I have the following DAG:

task_a >> task_b >> task_c

I would like to be able:

to somehow access inside task_c some parameters (environment variables to be precise) passed to task_b (which is a KubernetesOperator)
without changing task_b (so no xcom involved: because of the legacy code base I'm working on, I would like to avoid having to modify task_b whatsoever and so I don't want to have task_b pushing xcom)

I found and tried some stackoverflow post (Airflow: Get previous task id in the next task) where I can access the previous task_id from a given task. I would like to know if, using the same spirit, I could access the previous task context in my task.

If parameters are deterministic, just pass them to task_B AND to task_C.

Can you confirm if in your airflow database if the executor_config column of the task_instance_history is filled with pickled data? It should be possible to unpickle this data to a V1Pod object and introspect it for environment variables
